# I am running Kibana 7.8.1 on windows. I am trying to share kibana dashboard to external web app by embedding the iframe

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, kibana-7

I have a Kibana Dashboard or visualization that I'd like to embed in an external web page. However, I want users to be able to access this dashboard or visualization directly without being redirected to the Kibana login page. The goal is to provide a seamless user experience without requiring users to log in separately to view this specific content. using iframe. or is there any other way.

I've explored a few approaches to enable direct access to a Kibana Dashboard or visualization from my external web page, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired outcome.